# A function such that $f(0) = 1$ and $f(x) = x$ otherwise

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Let $x$ be a real number and $f$ a function such that $f(x)=x$ if $x\not=0$ and $f(0)=1$.

Does there exist a function like this, with an algebraic formula?

**EDIT**: Thank you for your answers, I know a function can be described that way, but I'm really searching the "*algebraic formula version*" of this function.

**EDIT 2**: I forgot mentionning it, but I'm searching a solution without the $sign$ function.

Comment: "algebraic formula" doesn't mean any one thing. To get the answer you're looking for, you have to specify what functions are allowed, and what functions aren't. If we can't use the signum function, can we use the step function? Can we only use polynomials of $x$?

Comment: Not all functions have an "algebraic formula", and that's okay.

Comment: Is the function going to be expressed as a computer program? If it is, the counter-arguments based on continuity don't apply, and you can get what you want.

Comment: This function is going to be used in one of my project, to transform a computer program to one-line algebra. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What about $$f(x)=x + 0^{x^2} $$ ?

---

For the question of definition of $0^0$ see this [paragraph in wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Zero_to_the_power_of_zero)

Comment: With this function, f(0) = 0, no ?

Comment: @Pyrofoux: Where did you see, that $0^0=0$? Usually it is assumed to be $0^0=1$

Comment: I put the function on Wolfram Alpha and $f(x)$ was equal to $0$. But I think you're right, thank you. :)

Comment: @Gottfried Helms, Pyrofaux:  even though, strictly speaking, I would question the assertion that the function $f(x) = x + 0^{x^2}$ is *algebraic*, I must say I found the cited wikipedia page both  very informative and educational.  Interesting interpretation!  Congratulations Gottfried, on acceptance of your answer, and +1 to boot!  Cheers!

Answer (score 7):

Sure, such a function exists.  The way you would generally write the formula for this function is
$$
f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
x & x \neq 0\\
1 & x = 0
\end{cases}
$$
This is called a "piecewise" definition of a formula.

Alternatively, we have the following one liner:
$$
f(x) = x+\lim_{b\to\infty}b^{-|x|}
$$

Comment: Thank you, but I'm searching a on-line version.

Comment: All right, what functions can we use, then, to make $f(x)$?

Comment: I'm searching a solution using only additions,multiplications,power,square root.

Comment: Well then, as the other answer indicates, no such formula exists. Any formula written like that describes a function that is continuous, except at its infinite discontinuities.

Answer (score 4):

Probably not, in fact I would say most definitely no, under any usual meaning of the term "algebraic formula".  An algebraic formula, as I understand it, is basically going to be a rational function in one indeterminate, call it $x$, over the reals in the present case since the question inquires into functions with real arguments.  Thus it would be of the general form $\frac{p(x)}{q(x)}$, with $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ polynomials with real coefficients which we can assume have no common polynomial factor $k(x)$.  Since $f(0) = 1$, we must have $p(0) = q(0) \ne 0$.  But the fact that $f(x) \to 0$ as $x \to 0$ implies we must have $p(0) = 0$, $q(0) \ne 0$, a contradiction.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you have described the function well.  The lack of an algebraic formula doesn't stop it being a function.  All that is required is that there be exactly one value for each element of the domain.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a one-liner, you may try $f(x) = x|\mathrm{sgn}(x)|+1-|\mathrm{sgn}(x)|$.

Comment: $f(-2) = 4 \ne -2$.

Comment: @njguliyev Somehow thought $x$ should be positive. Edited, thx.

Answer (score 2):

$1 - (\text{sgn } x)^2 (1-x)$ ?

Answer (score 2):

Answer addressing the poster's edits:

Note that if $f_1(x)$ and $f_2(x)$ are continuous functions, then their sum, product, difference, and composition are all continuous. And, their ratio is also continuous, unless the denominator equals zero at a point, in which case the function will be left undefined at that point! Since your function is discontinuous and defined at every point, it cannot be made using a finite number of products/sums/differences/compositions/ratios of continuous functions.

So, you'd have to allow either some infinite number of operations, or to start with a discontinuous everywhere-defined function.

Comment: I'm searching a solution using only additions,multiplications,power,square root. Are you saying that's impossible ?

Comment: Yes, because $1+x$, $2*x$, $x^2$, $4^x$, and $\sqrt{x}$ are all continuous (of course there are domain issues with $4^x$ and $\sqrt{x}$). And what I stated means that no finite number of the operations listed will do for creating a function with the properties like the one you listed!

Comment: @Pyrofoux also, mention it if you don't understand what I mean by "continuity"! But the intuitive definition should be fine, here - the function is discontinuous because it jumps at zero, and things like $1+x$ are continuous because there are no jumps.

Answer (score 0):

How about $f(x) = x + \frac{\delta(x)}{\delta(x)}$, where $\delta$ is the Dirac-function?

Comment: Isn't that just $x+1$ (if it's at all defined at $x\neq 0$)?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, $\delta(x) = 0$ where $x \neq 0$.

Comment: Okay, so when $x\neq0$: $\frac{\delta(x)}{\delta(x)}=\frac00=?$

Comment: Honestly, I don't know (as I cheated, because $\delta(x) = \inf$ at $x = 0$, so $\frac{\delta(x)}{\delta(x)}$ may not make any sense either.